# loop through multiple json files from website links

Tags: python, json, loops

i have used python to grab information from a json file available from an internet link, and save the parts i want in a csv. my code works for 1 file but there are multiple files (which i have different links to). the json files are exactly the same format (data from sports games in the league i coach).

my code looks like this:

```
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests
website = 'https://www.diferentwebsites.json'
r = requests.get(website)
contents = r.json()
```

then i grab some elements from the json and save it as a csv (actually 2 csv's, one for each team)... (which i later combine for all games). I made this work for this year by running the code 100 times manually pasting the link in each time, then ran a line to combine all the csvs (i am sure there is a "better way" but it "works")

is there an easy way to make a list of website links (say in a text file or separate csv) and do a "for each" type line so that i run my code on each website in a list to create the csv's for the entire season?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting all the sites in a list and then looping through each site ?

```
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests

websites = ['a','b','c']
contents_list = []

for site in websites:
    website = site
    r = requests.get(website)
    contents = r.json()
    contents_list.append(contents)
```

if there all in a file you can open the file and loop through it and create a list and then use the above method

Comment: thankyou - i was trying without the contents_list = []
obviously getting errors - just tested it with links to just 2 games so i could confirm it works quickly!

next season i won't have to do each game!